# Which of the following ways works better to prevent XSS attacks?

Tags: c#, encoding, xss

I am implementing input encoding to prevent XSS attacks and I have few questions.

1. Is it better to encode inputs and store the encoded data in the database? If so, how do you deal with string comparison in the whole project? Do you encode the string to compare as well? It seems like a "not so good" approach, because I'd have to adjust the whole project and future programmers have to remember this every time they compare two strings.
2. Should I throw the inputs directly into the database and encode them in response? This seems like a better way, but I'm not really sure. That's why I post here. Also, if this is the preferred way, is there any database management application (like phpMyAdmin etc.) that executes JavaScript directly from the database?

This is the first time I'm doing it, so I'd love some insight from more experienced developers.

Comment: Yes, (2) is definitely the better way. Also, use a template engine that does it automatically.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for quick response. I am currently using AntiXSSEncoder class available in .NET. Is it enough? Also, I updated the second question if you are interested.

Comment: I’m not an ASP.NET expert, but it seems kind of fragile – maybe prefer Razor? Re: your edit: no, that would be a horrible vulnerability in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Ryan Alright. Thanks once again. You could post it as an answer I guess, because I'm not really sure what else can I do besides accepting it.

Comment: I’d wait for someone who is an ASP.NET expert to come by with definitive templating advice. =) The bit on not HTML-encoding things before putting them in your database applies universally, though.

Comment: @Ryan The thing is, our backend is just full REST API (only serving JSON's), so I'm not sure if some template will be of any use :)

Comment: If you’re only serving JSON, your server side shouldn’t be concerned with HTML escaping at all! No HTML is being produced, after all. If you have a client that consumes those data, that’s its concern.

Comment: @Ryan That seems more than reasonable. I've been tasked to do this, because someone found out, that one of the libraries our frontend uses is vulnerable to this and executes the scripts.

Comment: Definitely need to fix the frontend library or at least do the transformation on the client before it gets to the library, then. Are you at liberty to say which library it is?

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately, I don't know. Our penetration testing guys detected this, but didn't say which library. I'm going to try to convince them to fix it on the frontend side then :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this many time before, but 2 is definitely the right approach, but let's adjust it a bit.

On the way in, you want to validate you data to make sure the data is valid according to the domain. For instance you might want to disallow certain characters (or better yet, use a white list of allowed characters). There is for instance no reason why a person's name should be allowed to include a "<". If invalid input is included we reject the request.
This may stop some attacks, but definitely not all of them.

Output escaping we apply when we transfer data from one context into another. We want to make sure data stays the data. So when we insert data into SQL, we use prepared statements, when we want to put the data into XML or HTML we encode if for those. There are different contexts, and we need to encode for the right context. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet.

The trouble will encoding and storing the encoded value in the database is:

1. You don't know the right encoding. Is the data supposed to be shown in a HTML attribute, between tags etc.? Different contexts require different encoding.
2. What if the encoding function is wrong, and you missed something. If you store encoded data, you have to go back and fix all the wrongly encoded data, instead of just updating the encoding function
3. What if you want to show data in a context where encoding isn't needed (e.g. a mobile app). Then it's going to look ugly.

My preferred approach these days would be to use a solid templating framework like react (which also encodes the data properly for you).

Comment: This is more or less what I was expecting and now I'm sure about it. Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it.